# Hide authorized menu item in asp.net web.sitemap

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, asp.net-2.0, membership, sitemap

I have a web.sitemap with security trimming enabled, however I need to hide a menu item based on a role to a page that has no access rules in the web.config.

i.e I have a Campaign page that is used to view existing campaigns as well as to add new campaigns, but I want the "New Campaigns" menu item to be hidden for anonymous users.
I tried adding the role name to the roles attribute in the web.sitemap but this has no effect.

I'm sure there must be a quick way to do this without modifying the sitemap provider which is my next port of call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is just a special case for anonymous users, you could create a second SiteMap.

Create a new file WebAnon.sitemap.
Create a new sitemap provider in the web.config

```
<add name="anonProvider" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="WebAnon.sitemap" securityTrimmingEnabled="true"/>
```

Set the SiteMapDataSource's [SiteMapProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sitemappath.sitemapprovider.aspx) property to "anonProvider" in the code behind if its an anonymous user.

Comment: I was hoping that there was a way to do it "out the box", but looks like I'm gonna have to create a new sitemap provider.

Comment: thanks ,but I do not understand why adding the "?" to rules in web.sitemap gives Authorization rule names cannot contain the '?' character error

Answer (score 1):

The `roles` attribute in a `<siteMapNode />` is an "allow" list, not a deny. Create/modify a corresponding `<location />` element in web.config to allow authenticated users and deny anonymous; e.g.

```
<location path="campaigns.aspx">
 <system.web>
  <authorization>
   <allow users="*" />
   <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
 </system.web>
</location>
```

BTW, if you're using a Windows principal and roles, any changes to your group membership don't take effect until you log off and then back on.

Comment: This won't work because the same page is used to view Campaigns by anonymous users. Therefore I need to be able to simply hide the menu item without actually locking it down, in this instance the Page handles the different security states.